# Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have this line in a .htaccess file

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch ExecCGI Includes IncludesNOEXEC SymLinksIfOwnerMatch ExecCGI Includes IncludesNOEXEC SymLinksIfOwnerMatch ExecCGI Includes IncludesNOEXEC SymLinksIfOwnerMatch ExecCGI Includes IncludesNOEXEC SymLinksIfOwnerMatch ExecCGI Includes IncludesNOEXEC SymLinksIfOwnerMatch ExecCGI Includes IncludesNOEXEC SymLinksIfOwnerMatch ExecCGI  Includes  IncludesNOEXEC  SymLinksIfOwnerMatch  Indexes -Indexes
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may.
```

How can I fix this and still do the samething?

Better yet what does this line do and is it even needed?

Comment: This line doesn't make any sense at all, it's the same stuff over and over again, and is contradicting itself (`Indexes -Indexes`). Read the docs to learn what the options mean and then write a new line that does what you need. The error message itself should be self-explanatory. Lastly, I guess this is Apache 2.4, not 2.2 as you tagged it?

Comment: I took over this server. Dont have much experience with this.

Comment: Me neither. I'd try Googling the terms `htaccess options` to start. You could also Google the text of the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer to your question is contained within the error message.

The right thing to do in this case would be to smack whoever wrote that line, and make a list of each option specified.  If it appears with a minus at all, put it in once with a minus.  If it appears only bare or with a plus, put it in once with a plus.

I believe you just want this:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI +Includes +IncludesNOEXEC -Indexes
```

Why this particular option set is required in that area, I don't know.  But, feel free to read the documentation for an explanation of each one, and see how or if your use case requires it.