# Apache Options missing Plus/Minus sign

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, options

I have to migrate an Apache web server from version 2.2 to version 2.4. In Apache 2.2, I find the following Options directive in the virtual host configuration files:

```
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

Now, that this syntax is invalid in 2.4

```
Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may
```

I wonder what the previous syntax is equivalent with. Do I have to prepend a `+` or a `-` to `FollowSymLinks`?

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. http://serverfault.com/questions/647665/either-all-options-must-start-with-or-or-no-option-may

Comment: My downvote was for not showing any research effort. I can't believe it as easier to write this question than it was to go and read the documentation. Equally the quoted error message seems rather explicit.

Comment: The error message is clear, but it does not say what to prepend to keep in pace with Apache 2.2. I never saw this syntax of missing signs before, and the documentation of Apache 2.2 is not quite clear about this. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html

Comment: To NOT overwrite the Options that are already set you put a plus or minus sign in front of the Option that you want to change. http://support.modwest.com/content/1/44/en/what-options-are-configured-with-apache-and-what-can-i-do-with-htaccess-files.html

Answer (score -1):

Missing signs are to be replicated to subsequent arguments.